# JS - How to get middle Wednesday of given month

Tags: javascript, date

For example say we look at the date 01/2018...
There are 5 Wednesdays in that month so we would return '01/17/2018' because it belongs to the 3rd Wednesday of the month

However, if we look at 02/2018...
There are 4 Wednesdays in that month so we would return '02/14/2018' because it belongs to the 2nd Wednesday of the month

The midpoint formula doesn't quite work here (at least I don't think it does)

Is this how I should plan everything out or is there a simpler way?

```
function returnMidWednesday(month, year){
  //How many days in month
  var daysInMonth = new Date(year,month,0).getDate();

  //How many Wednesdays in that month

  //If Wednesdays total == 4 return 2nd
  //If Wednesdays total == 5 return 3rd
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The algorithm isn't likely to be simple given that the days in a month changes as does the first of the month. There are months with 28, 29, 30 and 31 days. The last three can have 4 or 5 Wednesdays.

One algorithm is:

1. Get the date of the first Wednesday of the month
2. Get the number of days in the month
3. Subtract the date of the first Wednesday from days in the month
4. If the result is 28 or greater, there is a 5th Wednesday so return the third
5. Otherwise, return the second

Here is an implementation:

```js
/* Return second Wednesday where there are 4 in a month
** Return the third Wednesday where there are 5 in a month
** @param {number} year - year
** @param {number} month - month
** @returns {Date} date of "middle" Wednesday
*/
function getMidWed(year, month) {

  // Create date for first of month
  var d = new Date(year, month - 1);

  // Set to first Wednesday
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + ((10 - d.getDay()) % 7));

  // Get days in month
  var n = new Date(d.getFullYear(), d.getMonth() + 1, 0).getDate();

  // Set to 3rd Wed if 28 or more days left, otherwise 2nd
  d.setDate(d.getDate() + (n - d.getDate() > 27? 14 : 7));

  return d;  
}

// Some tests
[[2000,2], [2000,5], [2012,2], [2012,5], [2018,1], [2018,2]].forEach(
  function(a) {
    console.log(getMidWed(a[0], a[1]).toString());
  }
);
```

Comment: Could you please explain what - 10 means in `(10 - d.getDay()) % 7)` ?

Comment: It adds the right number of days to the date to get the next Wednesday. E.g. if the day is Monday, *getDay* returns 1 so `10 - 1` is 9, then `9 % 7` is 2, Monday + 2 is Wednesday. Similarly Tuesday is 2, so `(10 - 2) %7` gives 1, Tuesday + 1 is Wednesday. Thursday is 4, so `(10 - 4)%7` is 6, which sets it to Wednesday in the following week, etc.

Answer (score 0):

Pass month starting from 0 and year to this method it will print mid wed date in console in day/moth/year formte

```
function returnMidWednesday(month, year) {
    var date = new Date(year, month, 1);

    if (date.getDay() != 0 && date.getDay() <= 3) {
        //month has 5 wed
        // 3 means wed day index from week
        var day = 21 - (date.getDay() + 3);
        console.log(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
    } else {
        //month has 4 wed
        // 3 means wed day index from week
        //7 means total number of days in week
        var day = 14 - (date.getDay() + 3) % 7;
        console.log(day + "/" + (month + 1) + "/" + year);
    }
}
```

Comment: The result of `String(date)` is implementation dependent and is different in different browsers, you should not rely on it returning any particular value. Date's have a [*getDay*](http://ecma-international.org/ecma-262/8.0/#sec-date.prototype.getday) method that returns an integer indicating the day of the week. This algorithm doesn't work: in February, even if the first day is Wednesday, there are only 4 in the month.

Comment: what was your test case for feb means year?

Comment: i have tested with different possibilities

Comment: It fails for February 2000, which has 4 Wednesdays. The second is the 9th, this function returns the 16th.